# html bind a range element with a number element angularjs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, pug, meanjs

I have a MEAN stack based app and I am using jade for templating

Now, I am trying to bind two elements (range and number) so that the user is able to either select the value by range element or by entering a number in the number type input.

```
.row.col-lg-12.col-md-12.col-xs-12.col-sm-12.form-group
    .col-md-4.col-lg-4.col-xs-12.col-sm-12
        label.ng-binding(for="quantity") Quantity
    .col-md-4.col-lg-4.col-xs-12.col-sm-12
        input.form-control(type="range",min="0",max="{{sale.transaction.newItem.item.stock}}",step="1", ng-model="sale.transaction.newItem.quantity", name="quantity")
.row.col-lg-12.col-md-12.col-xs-12.col-sm-12.form-group
    .col-md-4.col-lg-4.col-xs-12.col-sm-12
        label.ng-binding Note: Please slide the bar to change the quantity of item selected.
    .col-md-4.col-lg-4.col-xs-12.col-sm-12
        input.form-control(type="number", value={{sale.transaction.newItem.quantity}}, ng-model="sale.transaction.newItem.quantity")
```

When I tried this I am not getting any value in the second input element even If I change the value from the range element

Comment: I suggest you look at http://jsfiddle.net/bmleite/2pk3m/2/

Comment: @SimonH I'm not sure where that example came from, but it's not fully functional;  changing the range control doesn't change the value as it should.